# How to send SMS from a website (without a paid service)?

Tags: javascript, html, web, sms

Using modern web technology, is there a library/API for sending SMS messages via a website? I've seen existing pay-for services, but I just want something really simple so I'd like to implement it myself if possible.

Comment: How many texts per day do you anticipate sending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could essentially send them as emails to the email box for that phone number. It would then get forwarded as an SMS to their phone. The problem with this is that you would then need a way to look up the carrier of the phone number you are sending to, and you would have to worry about which carriers you could and could not cover. Essentially, you're going to have a hard time doing this without paying.

T-Mobile: phonenumber@tmomail.net

AT&T: phonenumber@txt.att.net

Sprint: phonenumber@messaging.sprintpcs.com

Verizon: phonenumber@vtext.com